# rosjava set log level to WARN

Tags: java, ros

I wrote a ROS node using rosjava.
When it starts up, there are a few logging outputs like:

```
Loading node class: MyApp.RosWrapper
Jun 18, 2015 3:12:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar <init>
INFO: MasterXmlRpcEndpoint URI: http://localhost:11311
Jun 18, 2015 3:12:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar onPublisherAdded
INFO: Registering publisher: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</mynode, http://127.0.0.1:39009/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
```

I've found out that rosjava uses the `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` approach (see https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/blob/indigo/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/node/client/Registrar.java#L54)

To configure this, you should normally put a file called `commons-logging.properties` in your Classpath. I tried to add the folder containing this file to the classpath, but nothing changed.

UPDATE:

I found out that by default rosjava uses the `Jdk14Logger` class.

**How can I decrease the log-level to e.g. `WARN`? Where do I have to put the corresponding config files?**

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer**: As stated in the comment, this does **not** work for `rosjava` and therefore does **not** answer the question. I do not delete the post, however, to keep records that this has already been tried.*

### Permanent setting

To permanently modify the log-level, create a file and add something like the following:

```
# Set the default ros output to warning and higher
log4j.logger.ros=WARN
# Override my package to output everything
log4j.logger.ros.my_package_name=DEBUG
```

For ROS to use this file, you have to define the environment `ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE` and set it to the path of your file. This can be done by adding the following line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/config_file
```

See also the [ROS wiki about rosconsole configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration).

### Temporary setting

If you only want to temporarily change the log-level for a currently running node, you can use the tool `rqt_logger_level`. This will start a GUI where you can change the log-level for each running node. The settings are not stored, however, so it will be lost after restarting the node.

Comment: I just tested your suggestion. It works for roscpp nodes, but not for rosjava. Setting the log level to WARN, the rosjava node still outputs INFO messages.

Comment: @SailAvid: Thanks for the feedback (strange that they use different settings for rosjava...). I added a comment to my answer, but for now I will not delete it, so others can see that this has already been tried.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the log levels for any ROSJava project, create a file like this one:

*log-config.properties*

```
# The following creates two handlers
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
# Set the default logging level for the root logger
.level=ALL
# log level for the "com.example" package
org.ros.logging.level=ALL
# Set the default logging level
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
# Set the default formatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
# Specify the location and name of the log file
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/home/robot/test.log
```

and later, load the configuration in the execution:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/robot/log-config.properties -jar rosjava-helloworld-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
```

Juan Antonio